# c # selenium button click

Tags: c#, selenium

[image]

hello, i want help for c # selenium. I'll make a click action, but the button doesn't have an id.

```
<button type="submit" class="block w-full mb-4 py-3 bg-green-400 font-semibold text-center text-sm text-white hover:bg-green-500 rounded">
Kayıt Ol
</button>
```

I would be glad if you tell me how to do this.

[image]

Comment: can you post your code as text, because it's hard to correct images of code, and we cant copy/paste them, thanks

Comment: Why not write a matching selector for that button? You don't need to select such a button by ID, you can also traverse the DOM, or search it by the text used inside

Answer (score 0):

If the button doesn't have id you can use another locator strategy like XPath, name, class ,css etc.

refer this : https://www.journaldev.com/29481/locators-in-selenium

You can use the below code :

```
  XPATH  = //button[text()='Kayıt Ol']

 m_driver.FindElement(By.XPATH("//button[text()='Kayıt Ol']"))
```